# how to read msg attachment in c#

Tags: c#

i am having msg file and there i am having pdf attachment .i want to know the pdf file name and i have to write filename in one excel .i have tried some coding which has got from online.

```
public static void SaveAttachments(string msgPath)
{

    var message = new OutlookStorage.Message(msgPath);


    foreach (var attachment in message.Attachments)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("File '{0}'.", attachment.FileName);

        attachment.SaveAsFile(path + attachment.FileName);
    }
}
```

Comment: OK. What is your question?

Comment: This question's code seems a copy of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20567357/how-to-extract-pdf-attachments-from-msg-file-in-c) what is not working for you?

Comment: OutlookStorage.Message(msgPath); while using this assembly missing Exception showing.what dll i have to use for this.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Steve.